# Lon/Lat Order when using spatial POINT type with MySQL

Tags: mysql, point

What is the correct order when setting a POINT in MySQL?

Even the answers in SO questions differ on this:
[Moving lat/lon text columns into a 'point' type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756232/moving-lat-lon-text-columns-into-a-point-type-column)

Is it

```
POINT(lat lon)
```

or

```
POINT(lon lat)
```

As far, as i see it, it should be the first version (lat lon) as the POINT takes as params x and y, but i was not able to find an definite evidence.

Comment: You can try both ways and see what works, can't you? I would count on Quassnoi's answer.

Comment: +1 though because I searched the MySQL docs for more than 3 minutes and couldn't find the relevant documentation.

Comment: The only thing I found was the the [`X()` and `Y()` functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/geometry-property-functions.html#point-property-functions) example.

Comment: Basically both work. And as you access them in MySQL with X() and Y() I can only assume, that POINT(lat lon) is the correct order. But as you say, it is not well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as one can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757054/1393681
the order is (lon lat).

<del>**lon** is basicly the y axis and **lat** the x if i look at my globe, but the **lon's are traveling along the x axis** and the **lat's along the y axis** so i think thats the reason why you **use (lon lat)**</del>

Despite that, if you stay consistent in your application it shoudn't matter if the world is flipped inside your db ;-)

Comment: You will confuse people. `lon` is the *x-axis*, and its gradations are displayed vertically. `lat` is the *y-axis*, so its gradations are horizontal. As with every 2D graph, gradations are perpendicular to the axis they measure.

Comment: it would be important to use POINT(lon lat) instead of POINT(lat lon) if you wish to use the GIS features built into MySQL 5.7+

Comment: holy i always assumed it was the other way around cuz google uses lat-lng format... why in the world does google use lat-lng if everythings supposed to be lng-lat?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `lat lon` to me. You can check this from your mysql shell:

```
mysql> SELECT ST_ASTEXT(coords), ST_LONGITUDE(coords), ST_LATITUDE(coords) FROM table;

+----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| ST_ASTEXT(coords)          | ST_LONGITUDE(coords)  | ST_LATITUDE(coords)  |
+----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| POINT(33.520571 -18.20072) | -18.20072             | 33.520571            |
+----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

Note: SRID 4326 used.

See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-point-property-functions.html#function_st-latitude

Answer (score -3):

Technically it does not matter.
You are storing into the x and y coordinates of a point.
You just have to read them the same way you write them.

If you care about a "proper way" I can only refer to the fact that Google Maps API creates coortinates using

```
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
```

and in school you also learn about "latitude and logintude", not the other way arround.

Still, technically it really doesn't metter which way you store them. Just make sure that you use the same convention when you read them back.

Comment: In programming, you will also find plenty of systems and functions which require lonlat parameters instead of latlon. However, in your DB, it still doesn't matter.