# What is the correct MySQL Polygon format for Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: mysql, geospatial, wkt

When looking at MySQL's [Polygon Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html) page, one can see comprehensive examples for using the polygon/spatial functions but it does not say something about the format of the polygon points.

An example of a polygon string is

```
Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0),(1 1,1 2,2 2,2 1,1 1))
```

but it is not clear whether it is using **LatLng** or **LngLat**.

What is the correct MySQL Polygon format for Latitude and Longitude?

Comment: Probably they are Euclidean. Guess you need Polar genometry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lon/Lat Order when using spatial POINT type with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082696/lon-lat-order-when-using-spatial-point-type-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis order for coordinates in WKT is Cartesian, so (X Y) or (longitude latitude).

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct format to LatLng if you are using Poylgon type on mysql because latLng is a POINT and not a Polygon.

So you must use a POINT type.

eg.

```
 POINT(-22.984439228720408 -43.2029068475822);
```