# POINT datatype for storing (lat,lag)

Tags: mysql

I've using POINT datatype for storing latitude and longitude in MYSQL 5.7

So How I store latitude and longitude to POINT:

`POINT(lat,lng)` OR `POINT(lng,lat)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `POINT(X,Y)`
- Longitude is x-axis and latitude is y-axis.

From the above terms we can understand `POINT(long,lat)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two different types.
At MYSQL you use: `POINT(lng,lat)` or long format: `Point([Longitude], [Latitude])`

At MS SQL you use: `POINT(lat,lng)` or long format: `Point([Latitude], [Longitude])`

Source: [SQL-server-helper.com](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx)

Comment: This is the *right answer* for MS SQL. Have a look [at this talk](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,209566,209566) about different GIS implementations and this [SO Entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082696/lon-lat-order-when-using-spatial-point-type-with-mysql) that `lon,lat` is the way to go for MYSQL.

Comment: i added the dwo different answers ;) THX!