# Is there a way to get POINT coordinate from Lat, Lng using MySQL functions?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-maps, mercator

I need to get mercator coordinates from `Lat`, `Lng` in Node.js. I can use some module (for example, [node-sphericalmercator](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sphericalmercator)). But it means that the calculation is done on the Node server, not in MySQL:

```
// Here is pseudo code example
var sphericalmercator = new Sphericalmercator();

res = "SELECT ALL lat, lng FROM table"

var rs = res.map(function(row) {
    return [sphericalmercator.forward([row.lng, row.lat])]
});

// and only then I can do subsequent INSERTs.
INSERT INTO table VALUES POINTFROMTEXT("POINT(rs[0] rs[1])")
```

But I'd like to covert `Lat`, `Lng` into `POINT` straightly in MySQL, not on Nodejs server. Is there some functions for this?

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES SomeFuncThatTraslatesToPoint(Lng, Lat)
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit i'm no expert, but is this something like what you're trying to do?

[Moving lat/lon text columns into a 'point' type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756232/moving-lat-lon-text-columns-into-a-point-type-column)

Specifically the section regarding `GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', lat, ' ', lng, ')'))`