# Lucene Spatial Search for Point inside a polygon

Tags: algorithm, lucene, polygon, geospatial, spatial

I have a KML file which contains many latitudes/longitudes which make up

> around 500 odd polygons (approx 6,000 points are present).

I also have a sample file which contains

> latitude and longitude for the entire area of say a particular city.
>   (approx 10 million odd points latitude/longitude)

I have been going around **Lucene Spatial** documentation from some time but I am unable to understand if it will serve the following purpose:

> a. To find for each point whether it lies inside some polygon or not.
>   (effectively a point can be either inside or outside all of the
>   polygons) with close to 100% accuracy.

As of now, I have achieved this usecase by

> implementing RayCrossing algorithm in Java

however

> I am inclined to use Lucene

as I am already using it for number of other usecases. Additionally RayCrossing algorithm is slow for such a huge number of points.

Please advise. Please point to some code samples which can get me started on achieving the usecase if it's possible using Lucene.

Comment: Are you talking about using the JTS plugin inside Lucene?

Comment: Don't really know.. But I need to understand if the usecase I am trying to achieve is even possible or not using Lucene ?. I guess JTS needs to be imported in case I am using polygon geometry.

Comment: Point in polygon for this number/size of polygons would be considered a fairly trivial use case of JTS.

Comment: Do you mean to say it won't produce the output..Without lucene it is taking 1 hour both using MySQL spatial methodology and custom implementation of RayCrossing algorithm. With lucene I expect the execution time to go down,

Comment: Before going down the Lucene route, have you considered converting your geometry to MySQL geometry, ie, a point and using Contains or Intersects with a spatial index. This kind of query should take milliseconds with a properly setup spatial index. Ray tracing is reinventing the wheel, imho.

Comment: See this post for some pointers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232316/table-structure-for-geo-spatial-data/25237180#25237180. I am not saying don't use Lucene, more that you should optimize your existing solution first.

Comment: Yes I am using MYSQL geometry and ST-Contains function to achieve this. However with so much of data, MYSQL is taking approx 1 hour to give me the complete output. Hence I was wondering if using Lucene will reduce the time taken.

Comment: had gone through the post when I was exploring why to use MySQL for this spatial analysis..