# Geo search a MySQL table for rows that are within proximity

Tags: python, mysql, gis, geospatial

I have an sql table that has some data on retail locations with `lat`, `long` coordinates. My application queries the table to pull the data using python. Here's some sample data:

```
table1

id  name   lat       long
1   post   37.788151 -122.407570
2   sutter 37.789551 -122.408302
3   oak    37.815730 -122.288810
```

I have a point coordinate `37.785980` and `-122.410851`, and I'd like to find rows from the table that are nearby, say within `0.5` mile radius from the coordinate.

Performance matters. I cannot query all rows due to poor performance, long time sending data to client application and storage / memory issues. Therefore, I need a SQL based solution.

Using SQL in python, how do I implement an efficient solution that does proximity search and returns rows that meet the distance condition? `Lat` and `Long` columns are stored as `TEXT`. Here's how I pull data from `sql` in `python`.

```
# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'pwd'
host =  'xxxx.1.rds.amazonaws.com'
port = 3306
database = 'db1'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))


# Readdata
con = engine.connect()

query = '''
        SELECT x
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY key
        '''

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)

con.close()
```

Happy to share more info if required for context.

Comment: Have you tried using a [spatial index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html) on a geometry type?

Comment: Alternatively, as a simpler alternative to a full spatial index, it sounds like you're currently loading every row from the database and doing all filtering on the client side. You could try finding a bounding box to contain your 0.5 radius search area, and excluding all longitude/latitude pairs which are outside that bounding box. Then you can do a more exact filter on the client side.

Comment: @NickODell yep, that make sense. Could you share how to implement that? I can modify the column type in SQL table if necessary.

Comment: I'd prefer to not load every row and do filtering in SQL query / server-side.

Comment: The SQL query to do this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756248/530160). PS: What version of MySQL are you using? You'll need version 8 or better for this to work well.

Comment: @NickODell `v8.0.27`. I am not sure if I need a Spatial Index? Although, I have created a `coords` column of `POINT` type using `Lat`,`Long` fields.

Comment: If you want to avoid a [full table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan), you need a spatial index. If you don't care, then you don't need one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243803/discussion-between-kms-and-nick-odell).

Answer (score 0):

Brute force requires a full table scan.  That does not scale well.

Starting with some indexes and using a "bounding box" gives an order of magnitude improvement.

So does using a SPATIAL index.

More discussion on those, plus even faster ways:  [*Find Nearest*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

PS.  Don't store numeric values as text strings.  (The link above talks about the 'right' datatype to use.